# running "Hello World!" on intellij-idea

Tags: eclipse

well, I'm new to Java and I was trying intellij with "Hello World" program:

```
class Jerry {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
   }
}
```

I I'm getting following error!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ArithmeticDemo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
```

the code is working perfectly on Eclipse!

Comment: What is `ArithmeticDemo`?

Comment: I really don't know! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you must have named your file `ArithmeticDemo.java`.

Please make sure your class name matches with your filename. In this case, you should have `Jerry.java`.

Also, your class needs to be `public`, regardless of whether you are in Eclipse or IntelliJ.

Comment: thnX for answering; 1) my filename was "Jerry.java" and it wasn't the problem 2) I make it public but the same error happened again 3) I change name of  the class "Jerry" to "ArithmeticDemo" and it worked!!!; But it seems weird! whay should I name my class "ArithmeticDemo"???

Comment: @JalalAghazadeh, Sounds like some kind of configuration issue with IntelliJ.

Comment: would it be fixed by reinstalling?

Comment: @JalalAghazadeh, That is unclear. A lot of programs leave configuration files even after they are re-installed. I would try starting a brand new project and seeing if that helps.